# Are SDL_EventType and SDL_Keycode gauranteed to have distinct underlying types?

Tags: c++, enums, sdl, typedef

I'm currently building an event manager to handle all sorts of callbacks. I want to handle SDL keyboard events separately from other SDL events whilst keeping my class's interface consistent. To this end I'm overloading methods, but I'm unsure if I'm creating ambiguous code.

I currently have two methods:

```
unsigned set_callback(SDL_EventType event_type, const std::function<void(const SDL_Event&)>& callback_func);
unsigned set_callback(SDL_Keycode key, const std::function<void(const SDL_Event&)>& callback_func);
```

In the docs SDL_EventType is listed as having an underlying [type of Uint32](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Event). I can't find any documentation listing the underlying type of SDL_Keycode. In the source it is [typedef'd to Sint32](http://www.libsdl.org/tmp/SDL/include/SDL_keycode.h), however this typedef appears to bear no relation to the enum declaring the keycodes. SDL seems to be relying on the compiler to make the underlying type of the Keycode enum a signed int because one of its values is less than zero (though I can't see which). If that negative value were to be removed in the future the compiler would presumably make the underlying type an unsigned int thus making my overloaded methods ambiguous.

So, does the SDL library guarantee that these two enumerations will always have distinct underlying types?

Comment: The SDL library is written in C and therefore has no operator overloading. In particular, they have no need of making `SDL_EventType` and `SDL_Keycode` be different types. Furthermore, enum values default to `int`, so a signed int32 (`Sint32`) can work well with the enum values.

Comment: I don't have an in-depth knowledge of C but I guess that makes sense. When I compile my code with g++ the correct overloaded method is chosen, however if overloading isn't a concern for the library developers the underlying types may be changed on a whim. I guess I'll have to bite the bullet and rename the second method.